# A reference for an inequality

Tags: calculus, reference-request

What can I reference to use the following inequality?

$$(1-x)^k <\frac{1}{1 + xk}, x\in (0,1), k\in \mathbb{N}, k \ge 1 $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a corollary to [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)

$$(1+a)^n \ge 1+na$$

for all $a>-1$ and $n\ge 1$.

$$ (1+kx) (1-x)^k \le (1+x)^k (1-x)^k = (1-x^2) ^k \le 1.$$